# How to show hide time in topbar when hovering?

Tags: 20.04, top-bar

How can I configure ubuntu topbar date and time to show only when I hover into topbar and when unhover it doesn't show.
I want to have this functionality only for date and time, not others.
[image: top bar]

Comment: Does [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/top-panel-auto-hide-ubuntu-20-04/) help? I doubt it can be set only for the date and time.

Comment: Hi It is only for whole topbar. But I want to do only for Date and time text inside it.

Comment: You will probably need to write your own Gnome Shell extension to achieve such effect.